# Elasticsearch multi term filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm quite new to Elasticsearch, so here's my question.
I wanna do a search query with elasticsearch and wanna filter with multiple terms.

If I want to search for a user 'tom', then I would like to have all the matches where the user 'isActive = 1', 'isPrivate = 0' and 'isOwner = 1'.

Here's my search query

```
"query":{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query":"*tom*",
                "default_operator": "OR",
                "fields": ["username"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": { 
                "isActive": "1",
                "isPrivate": "0",
                "isOwner": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use 2 terms, it works like a charm, but when i use 3 terms it doesn't.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The real answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383259/308851 -- it's a _list of term objects_ under filter which is _not at all_ evident from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html because there the value of filter is a _single_ term object.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You should use `bool filter` to `AND` all your terms:

```
"query":{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query":"*tom*",
                "default_operator": "OR",
                "fields": ["username"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {"term" : { "isActive" : "1" } },
                    {"term" : { "isPrivate" : "0" } },
                    {"term" : { "isOwner" : "1" } }
                ]
             }
         }
     }
}
```

For version 2.x+ you can use `bool` query instead of `filtered` query with some simple replacement: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Comment: I wonder why there is such an inconsistency between elastic versions.

Comment: Just in case I have a filter query for multiple values for single field how does it goes, for ex if there are three type ids : 1,2,3 and I need to filter with ids (containing 2  or 3)

Comment: You can use `terms` query, ref https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Answer (score 17):

As one of the comments says, the syntax has changed in recent ES versions. If you are using **Elasticsearch 6.+**, and you want to use a wildcard and a sequence of terms in your query (such as in the question), you can use something like this:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "your_field_name_1": {
              "value": "tom*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "your_field_name_2": {
              "value": "US"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "your_field_name_3": {
              "value": "Michigan"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "your_field_name_4": {
              "value": "0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) about wildcard queries:

> Note that this query can be slow, as it needs to iterate over many
>   terms. In order to prevent extremely slow wildcard queries, a wildcard
>   term should not start with one of the wildcards * or ?.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you really need to search with preceding wildcards you can use a trick and index an additional field with the flipped value (tom -> mot) and do an or search on it: originalfield:tom* or newfield:mot*. This should be faster.

Comment: According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html  `must` is no replacement for `filter`: "unlike `must` the score of the query will be ignored"