# Elasticsearch filter multiple terms with only matching results and not any of them

Tags: elasticsearch

How I can get only filtered matching results with all the multi term search. I have this sample table where titleid is a mapping int field and personid is a keyword:

```
titleid:1,personid:a
titleid:3,personid:a

titleid:1,personid:b
titleid:2,personid:b

titleid:1,personid:c
titleid:5,personid:c
```

The expeted result is:

```
titleid:1
```

With a sample query like this one:

```
{query:
    {bool:
    {filter:
            {must:[
                    {terms : {fields: {personid:[a,b,c]}}
                 ]
            }}}}
```

I have the following results:

```
titleid: 1,2,3,5
```

Maybe this will help, I did the query in sql and got the expected result. What I did was ask the query to give me the sum of titleid that matches the quantity of searched parameters. This is only to be more self explained, the idea is to use elasticsearch.

```
select titleid
from (
   select count(titleid) as title_count, titleid 
   from table1 
   where personid in ('a','b','c')
   group by titleid
) as vw 
where title_count = 3
```

Comment: please paste your actual elasticsearch output when you run the above query.

Comment: What are the conditions you want to use?

Comment: Hi Eli what Im trying to know is titleId, data that I don't have and only get the matching ones in all personIds. I only know personId for searching purposes.

Comment: is you dataset above correct?  parteid?  if so then I'm not sure you query or questions is making sense.  could you try to rephrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you only want records with `titleid == 1` AND `personid == 'a'` you can filter on  both fields.  only the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) uses `must`, `should`, and `most_not`.  with a filter since it's filtering (eg, removing) by definition it's a `must`

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "term": {
          "titleId": { "value": 1 }
        } 
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "personid": { "value": "a" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE::**

Now your question looks like you want to filter and [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html) your results and then aggregate on those.  There's a few [metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-metrics.html) and [bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket.html) aggregations

Using [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)  (this isn't tested but should be very close if not correct)

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "title_id" : {
            "filter" : { "terms": { "personid": ["a","b","c"] } },
            "aggs" : {
                "id_count" : { "count" : { "field" : "titleid" } }
            }
        },      
        aggs": {
            "count_filter": {
               "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "the_doc_count": "_count"
                  },
                  "script": "the_doc_count == 3"
               }
            }
         }  
    }
}
```

However, be aware that Pipeline aggregations work on the outputs produced from other aggregations, so the overall amount of work that needs to be done to calculate the initial doc_counts will be the same. Since the script parts needs to be executed for each input bucket, the opetation might potentially be slow for high cardinality fields as in thousands of thousands of terms.

Comment: Thank you denov for your answer, what Im trying to know is titleId, data that I don't have and only get the matching ones in all personIds. I only know personId for searching purposes. I will edit the question.

Comment: Taking in consideration that the Tsql query makes a subquery turn arround to get the specific result. It seems to be the right answer!. Thanks denov for the follow-up. bucket selector aggregation is.

Comment: Invaluable. Nowhere does Elasticsearch tell you that the value of `filter` can be a _list_ of objects as shown here.