# How to get the exact match of using DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

How mapping have role to find the search??

GET courses/_search

return is below

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0226655,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "courses",
        "_type" : "classroom",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.0226655,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Computer Internals 250",
          "room" : "C8",
          "professor" : {
            "name" : "Gregg Va",
            "department" : "engineering",
            "facutly_type" : "part-time",
            "email" : "payneg@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled" : 33,
          "course_publish_date" : "2012-08-20",
          "course_description" : "cpt Int 250 gives students an integrated and rigorous picture of applied computer science, as it comes to play in the construction of a simple yet powerful computer system. "
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "courses",
        "_type" : "classroom",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Computer Science 101",
          "room" : "C12",
          "professor" : {
            "name" : "Gregg Payne",
            "department" : "engineering",
            "facutly_type" : "full-time",
            "email" : "payneg@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled" : 33,
          "course_publish_date" : "2013-08-27",
          "course_description" : "CS 101 is a first year computer science introduction teaching fundamental data structures and algorithms using python. "
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

mapping  is below

```
{
  "courses" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "course_description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "course_publish_date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "professor" : {
          "properties" : {
            "department" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "email" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "facutly_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "room" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "students_enrolled" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to return the exact match phrase `professor.name=Gregg Payne`

I tried below query  as per direction from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

```
GET courses/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "professor.name" : "Gregg Payne"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your mapping look like?

Comment: @KirylZ added the mapping, how mapping have role to find the search??

Comment: Explained in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your mapping, here is the query that shall work for you -

```
POST http://localhost:9200/courses/_search

{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "professor.name.keyword" : "Gregg Payne"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answering your question in the comments - search is always about mappings :) In your case you use **Term query** which is about searching for exact values and it needs a keyword field. [Text fields get analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html):

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
> analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
> difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead

Comment: How to add  below one ` "professor.name.keyword" : "Gregg Payne" , "professor.facutly_type.keyword" : "part-time"` . i got error

Comment: what are u trying to achieve exactly? search by several fields in the same request?

Comment: professor.name=Gregg Payne and professor.facutly_type.keyword=part-time

Comment: Kiryl sorry to disturb you, two more queries required if i need exact match 1. `professor.name=Gregg Payne and professor.facutly_type.keyword=part-time`  2. `professor.name=Gregg Payne or  professor.facutly_type.keyword=part-time` . second one is or  and first one is and

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202775/elasticsearch-multi-term-filter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or

Comment: Basically you'll need a compound bool query with "must" for AND and "should" for OR